# How to avoid tab stop on the link?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to use `<a href` to display twitter bootstrap link:

```
<a rel="tooltip" href="#" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Tooltip">Tooltip is here</a>
```

But I would like to avoid tab stop on such elements. Usage of `tabindex="0"` doesn't help. How can I do the same?

Comment: If jQuery is an option, you can use [such trick](http://jsfiddle.net/8Be6m/) to disable the focus which for anchor element is achieved with tab.

Comment: You can set the tabindex to a higher value then all other elements of the page (unique way without js). Disabling this causes  accessibility issues.

Comment: @rcdmk, what kind of accessibility issue can be here? I think there is no way to show tooltip without mouse by default.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, doesn't sound very good since I have a lot of such elements.

Comment: @LA_ People use tabs to navigate between elements and some softwares use this as the navigation order among other factors. (More detail here: http://www.accessibleculture.org/articles/2010/05/tabindex/). If your objective is hide this link from screen readers and people with some limitations, there's no problem through.

Comment: @rcdmk, please post your reply about high values as answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Comment: @LA_ thanks, I'm doing that now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the tabindex to a higher value then all other elements of the page (unique way without js). Disabling this causes accessibility issues.

People use tabs to navigate between elements and some softwares use this as the navigation order among other factors. (More detail here: http://accessibleculture.org/articles/2010/05/tabindex). If your objective is hide this link from screen readers and people with some limitations, there's no problem through.

Answer (score 0):

tabindex 0 is the first element in the tab order. Try tabindex="-1".

Edit

According to [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) specification:

> This value must be a number between 0 and 32767

So technically, you cannot enter a negative number for this attribute.

But it does not say anything about removing an element from the tab order, apart from disabling it :

> Elements that are disabled do not participate in the tabbing order.

Comment: It works with regards to the tab stop, but tooltip doesn't work with such tabindex. And http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_tabindex.asp says that first element is 1.

Comment: Zero is the last one in HTML. Maybe you're confusing with VB or other event based ui that has the tabindex property.

Comment: According to new (HTML5) specs a negative value is allowed. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute