# How to remove tab stop from iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, tabindex

How can I remove tab stop from an `<iframe>`? The `<iframe>` is hosted on my domain.

I have tried following code:

```
var objIFrame = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
if (objIFrame != null) {   
   objIFrame.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
}
```

But still I get iframe focused.

Comment: tabindex is just the tab stop order. Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557563/how-to-avoid-tab-stop-on-the-link

Answer (score 1):

An iFrame does'nt really support tabbing or selecting, it's normally the document or body inside the iFrame that is selectable. Try something like:

```
var objIFrame = document.getElementById('my_iframe');
    objIFrame.contentDocument.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
    objIFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
```

Comment: i tried this, it didn't work for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/hnpLn/1/).  you can still tab through the website in the iframe.  perhaps i did something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I studied [Stripe Elements as an example](https://stripe.dev/elements-examples/) to figure this out - they use `<iframes>` to collect Credit Card numbers and have a smooth tab ring through all their fields.

No amount of setting `tabindex` on anything did it for me so I opted to do it in JavaScript instead. I fixed it by listening for the `<iframe>`'s window to be focused, and then redirecting that focus to the element I wanted it to. This requires you to be in control of the `<iframe>`'s contents.

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  document.getElementById('myInput').focus();
})
```

Here's an example:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    My input
    <input type="text" />
    <iframe src="https://www.example.com/iframe.html" />
  <body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    More inputs
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        document.getElementById('myInput').focus();
      })
    </script>
  <body>
</html>
```

I noticed this behavior was unique to Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox 76, but didn't affect Chrome 81 or Edge 81.